# Serilog LogContext in Blazor with IIS Site Bindings

Tags: c#, logging, iis, blazor, serilog-aspnetcore

I use **Serilog** in my **Blazor Server** Side Application, which deploy on **IIS** using site bindings
[image: IIS Site Bindings]

And I want to ensure that the logs(unhandled exceptions and my custom log info) on these sites are written to **different** folders by **hostname**.

My **Serilog Configuration**:

```
public static class HostBuilderExtension
{
  public static IHostBuilder AddSerilog(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
  {
    return hostBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
    {
      var appSettings = hostingContext.Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();
      loggerConfiguration
      .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
      .Enrich.FromLogContext()
      .WriteTo.Map("Hostname", "ms-hosting", (hostname, wr) =>
        wr.Async(to =>
        to.File(appSettings.GeneralLogsPath(hostname), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, shared: true)));
    });
  }
}
```

GeneralLogsPath

```
public string GeneralLogsPath(string hostname) => Path.Combine(AppLogsRoot, hostname, "General", "log.log");
```

Registration in **Program.cs**:

```
builder.Host.AddSerilog();
```

And my custom **Middleware** to push current hostname to LogContext:

```
using Serilog.Context;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Herbst.Acc2.CustomerWebUI.Classes;

public class ScopedLoggingMiddleware
{
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
  private readonly ILogger<ScopedLoggingMiddleware> _logger;
  public ScopedLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ScopedLoggingMiddleware> logger)
  {
    _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
  {
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    var hostname = context.Request.Host.Host;

    try
    {
      using (LogContext.PushProperty("Hostname", hostname))
      {
        await _next(context);
      }
    }
    //To make sure that we don't loose the scope in case of an unexpected error
    catch (Exception ex) when (LogOnUnexpectedError(ex))
    {
      return;
    }
  }

  private bool LogOnUnexpectedError(Exception ex)
  {
    _logger.LogError(ex, "An unexpected exception occured!");
    return true;
  }
}

public static class ScopedLoggingMiddlewareExtensions
{
  public static IApplicationBuilder UseScopedLogging(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
  {
    return builder.UseMiddleware<ScopedLoggingMiddleware>();
  }
}
```

In Program.cs

```
app.UseScopedLogging();
```

Can I be sure that the message from *test-t1.com* **will never written** to *\logs\test-t2.com*?

Comment: Did you test your code? Did you encounter any unusual situations?

Comment: @samwu, This code works well (at least in my tests). In particular, I want to understand why if I push hostname from test-t1.com middleware and get a sudden unhandled exception(without processing the request in the middleware) on test-t2.com it will be recorded in \logs\test-t2.com.

Comment: Can you share details about unhandled exception? Is it possible to debug the code with try catch to see the cause of the exception?

Comment: @samwu, I throw this exception myself to see where it will be written if I push the LogContext property in another url

Comment: I don't see exception in your post, or you can try open a case via : https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

> Here’s how logical call context works with asynchronous code.
> Logical call context data flows with ExecutionContext. This means that it’s not affected by ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false); you can’t “opt-out” of the logical call context. So the logical call context at the beginning of an async method will always flow through to its continuations.
> When an async method starts, it notifies its logical call context to activate copy-on-write behavior. This means the current logical call context is not actually changed, but it is marked so that if your code does call CallContext.LogicalSetData, the logical call context data is copied into a new current logical call context before it is changed. Note: the copy-on-write behavior of logical call contexts is only available on .NET 4.5.

[Read more about AsyncLocal here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html)

Pay attention to these:
So the **logical call context(AsyncLocal)** at the beginning of an **async method** will **always** flow through to its continuations(In your example this is all the middleware following the current one).

Therefore, in your case, **each request will have its own logical call context**, so you can be sure that the message from test-t1.com will never written to \logs\test-t2.com?